# executing java command remotely via ssh fails with GC error

Tags: java, garbage-collection, ssh, jvm

I've been attempting to execute a java application using SSH from a remote machine
but it quite doesn't work well :(

To execute this application on the local machine,
I wrote a shell script including java command, and it works okay on local.

So, I tried to execute this shell script remotely via ssh like below

```
ssh username@hostname execute.sh
```

It seemed to worked out at first, but then result in the following error, and shutdown.

> GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 929792): May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
>
> GC Warning: Out of Memory! Returning NIL!

I understood what the message means reading this page ( http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/debugging.html ),
yet, I have no idea how come this error occur only when I execute java command remotely.

Does anyone know anything about this?
Or, is there any better way to execute java command remotely
other than ssh?

Any idea or information will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
May

---

java version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "it works okay on local".  Is "local" the same machine as the remote one, and you're talking about it working when you're at a TTY vs when you're connecting remotely over SSH?  Also, is `ulimit -a` interesting?

Comment: Can you provide what you have in execute.sh script? Are you redirecting stdout & stderr anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked out using "expect" command. Still I don't know the reason of the GC Warnings thou.. 
Thank you guys for all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between exec'ing a command locally vs remotely would be the environmental variable setup. Please check that environment variables your program might be using (such as JAVA_HOME) are being set to expected values

Comment: qwerty:
There's no problem about the environmental variables. Thanks :)